# Add inner effect when item selected in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view and i want to add an image , with inner effect when one item is selected .

I made this but when i do scroll another item has the same effect and i don't want. How can i change this ?

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cellO =  [self.collection cellForItemAtIndexPath:celulaSelectata];

    if ([selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {

        UIImage *inerImager =(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        cellO.inner.hidden=YES;
        return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    }
    else {
        cellO.inner.hidden=NO;
        return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    }
}


-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCell *cellOne =  [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cellOne.inner.hidden=YES;
    recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    recipeImageView.frame=CGRectMake(recipeImageView.frame.origin.x, recipeImageView.frame.origin.y, 100, 100);
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
       selectedIndexPath = nil;
        [self.player stop];

        CollectionViewCell *cellOne =  [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cellOne.inner.hidden=YES;


        recipeImageView.frame=CGRectMake(recipeImageView.frame.origin.x, recipeImageView.frame.origin.y, 100, 100);
        recipeImageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

    }
    else {
        celulaSelectata=indexPath;
        UICollectionViewCell  *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CollectionViewCell *cellOne =  [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        recipeImageView.frame=CGRectMake(recipeImageView.frame.origin.x, recipeImageView.frame.origin.y, 100, 100);
        cellOne.inner.hidden=YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because cells are reused. In your CollectionViewCell class you have to implement the method:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    //Clear the effect here.
}
```

Comment: no visible interface for UIVIewController declares the selector prepareForReuse.....and what should i put in this method if i want to hidde the inner ?

Comment: you have to imlement this in your CollectionViewCell class not in your view controller. If you have not subclassed UICollectionViewCell you have to do it in order to implement this method.